# Correlation matrix with huge dataset - Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In python, when I have a dataset X, whose rows are the different elements of the sample and the columns are different feature of the sample, I usually calculate the correlation matrix as follows (assuming zero mean):

```
import numpy as np
np.transpose(X).dot(X)/row
```

Now I have a dataset X that has 10 milion rows and 1 milion of columns, and if I try to calculate that correlation matrix, the computer remains blocked. 
The alternative of performing a for-loop seems to me impracticable, because is very slow also with smaller datasets.

How shoul I manage such amount of data?

Comment: 1 million columns? What kind of data requires 1 million *columns*? You may want to rethink your problem, because this type of dataset may cause problems elsewhere as well.

Comment: @Evert It is a dataset from a natual language processing problem: rows are documents, while columns are booleans: column i indicates wether the word that in the dictionary occupies the position i is or not present in the document.

Comment: _"How shoul I manage such amount of data?"_ — My advice is. start with a subset of it and build a feeling with it: which data structures, which algorithms do the best, which results are important and which can be neglected... Later a more knowledgeable you will be able decide how much of the data is significant and how you are going to process it.

Comment: Why not, for each document, store a list of position indices where the word can be found. An empty list means the word is not there, a list like [5432, 12345] means the word is found in positions 5432 and 12345. Those lists will be a lot shorter than a million columns of boolean flags.

Comment: have you looked at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html . Given you have a million features, unless each document is massive, you must by definition have lots of negatives, you shouldnt be storing it all in a normal matrix.

Comment: Just found on PyPi

[***bitarray-0.8.1*** **efficient arrays of booleans -- C extension**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1)

From their blurb:  _This module provides an object type which efficiently represents an array of booleans._

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a generator? I don't know if it would be acceptably fast but it would be better memory-wise so that the computer won't block.
Something like this https://gist.github.com/thatdatabaseguy/2577076

Paraphrasing the example:

```
import numpy as np

def my_gen(some_tuple):
    for each in some_tuple:
        yield each

X = np.fromiter(my_gen(database.get_data()))  # get_data() would return a cursor
```

**Edit**:
This is in the case you cannot find another way of reducing/ transforming/ splitting your data. Either way it is going to be difficult to handle on a single computer.
Good luck!